# trying to write a parallel and correct sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parallelism

I am trying to form a parallel sentence.  My first attempt is this:

"Good health requires right eating and regular exercising."

But I am not sure if this is grammatically correct.  The other way I can write it is:

"Good health requires right diet and regular exercise."

Which of these options is more suitable?

Comment: Both are correct and define parallel structures.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh - I agree. If you make this into an answer, the OP can officially accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that "right eating" is an unusual and off-puttign phrase.  I woulds suggest "proper" instead, which gives

> Good health requires proper diet and regular exercise.

This is a parallel construction and fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Good health requires right eating and regular exercising.

Correct. This is a parallel structure. **eating** and **exercising** are both gerunds.

> Good health requires right diet and regular exercise.

Correct as well. **diet** and **exercise** both are nouns.

The part of speech of both phrases remain the same and hence, they are parallel structures.

Comment: "right eating" and "right diet" are both pretty awkward phrases to a native English speaker.